# Upgrading from 4.1.5 database to 4.6.2 failing with constraint violation

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade a 4.1.5 database to 4.2.6. I am getting a constraint violation. See the screenshot.

[image: CiviCRM upgrade tasks]

[image: Attempted upgrade from 4.1.5 to 4.2.20]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take smaller steps, starting with 4.2. You can download the latest version of 4.2 from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/) (the latest in that series is currently [4.2.20](http://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/4.2.20/)).

If that upgrade goes ok, then you could proceed to 4.4 (the current LTS) and then up to 4.6.

Remember to backup your database before upgrading, and if the upgrade fails, restore from the backup before trying again.

Comment: I have treid to update to 4.2.20. from 4.1.5. I immediately get an error that a table exits. I've attached the screen shot to the original question

Comment: Are you sure you are starting with a 4.1 db that hasn't already been partially upgraded?

Comment: That should not be the case. It is a mysqldump of the current production database.

Answer (score 0):

You may not care to keep all the log info in your live database so long as you have a backup. If so, run

```
TRUNCATE civicrm_log;
```

on your sql db before running the upgrade.